# href link not working after editing css

Tags: html, css, firefox, href, preview

I'm trying to update my friend's website and she needs to keep the Genbook button. I copied and pasted the code from her current site into the code I'm currently writing, and it works fine until I try to format it in CSS. Since I want it centered under her logo I need to edit the CSS. I don't understand why editing the CSS would cause the link to become inactive.

Live preview in Firefox: active and unformatted [active link, without CSS (notice mouse cursor)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MADuS.png)

Live preview in Firefox: inactive and formatted [inactive link, with CSS (notice mouse cursor)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIrFF.png)

```css
#genbook {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="genbook">
  <script src="https://www.genbook.com/bookings/booknowjstag.action?id=30216717&size=medium"></script>
  <noscript>
    <a href="https://www.genbook.com/bookings/slot/reservation/30216717?bookingSourceId=1000">
      <img src="https://www.genbook.com/bookings/images/booknow-button-medium.png" width="150" height="50" alt="Make an Online Appointment" border="0">
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.genbook.com" style="font-size:10px;"></a>
  </noscript>
</div>
```

Now I'm even more confused! It appears to be working on Codepen and Code Snippet. So... why would it work in preview and then not work in preview?

New question: How do I know if it's really working?

Comment: most likely a z-index issue, something is covering the link

Comment: Following the comment above, just inspect the element in the browser console (right click). There you can see if there's anything getting in the way.

Comment: @DerekS  Now that you both mention it, that's probably what it is since I'm trying to put a background slideshow (which also isn't working) on the whole page (see example website asula com). Not sure how to rectify this... I might have to put the button somewhere else. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

your code, you postet, was in a `<noscript></noscript>` tag and `<script src="https://www.genbook.com/bookings/booknowjstag.action?id=30216717&size=medium"></script>` loaded a different code into your DOM, which does not worked. You can remove it an the noscript and it will work.

```css
#genbook {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="genbook">
    <a href="https://www.genbook.com/bookings/slot/reservation/30216717?bookingSourceId=1000">
      <img src="https://www.genbook.com/bookings/images/booknow-button-medium.png" width="150" height="50" alt="Make an Online Appointment" border="0" />
    </a>
</div>
```